# How can I visualize temporal network using graph-tool?

Tags: python, cairo, graph-tool

I have 20 directed graphs in grap-tool (Python 3.4) and all have the same node name (it is an attribute, called 'name'), but vary in terms of connections and attributes.

I am trying to plot those networks across time (i.e., how the edges changed at every timestep, and how the attributes such as color changed). For that, I need to fix the position of the nodes for all plots.

I tried this:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt

## networks = {dictionary of time as the key and the Graph as the value}

#getting the positions of the nodes once that should be fixed across Graphs
initial_pos = gt.arf_layout(networks[0],weight=None, d=0.5,
                    a=10, dt=0.001, epsilon=1e-06, max_iter=100, pos=None, dim=2)

for round_id in range(0,20):
    G = networks[round_id]
    fixed_pos = gt.arf_layout(G, max_iter=0, pos=initial_pos)
    deg = G.degree_property_map("in")
    deg.a = 15 * deg.a + 25
    gt.graph_draw(
        G,
        #pos=fixed_pos,
        vertex_fill_color=G.vertex_properties["color"],
        vertex_font_size=18,
        vertex_size = deg,
        vertex_shape = G.vertex_properties["shape"],
        edge_pen_width = 5,
        output_size=(1000, 1000), 
        output=("{0}.pdf".format(round_id))
    )
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-4efd39b32b83> in <module>()
      5     #f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(17, 10), sharex=True)
      6     G = nx2gt(networks[round_id])
----> 7     fixed_pos = gt.arf_layout(G, max_iter=0, pos=initial_pos)
      8     deg = G.degree_property_map("in")
      9     deg.a = 15 * deg.a + 25

/Users/amaatouq/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py in arf_layout(g, weight, d, a, dt, epsilon, max_iter, pos, dim)
    393 
    394     ug = GraphView(g, directed=False)
--> 395     libgraph_tool_layout.arf_layout(ug._Graph__graph, _prop("v", g, pos),
    396                                     _prop("e", g, weight), d, a, dt, max_iter,
    397                                     epsilon, dim)

/Users/amaatouq/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graph_tool/__init__.py in _prop(t, g, prop)
    177         raise ValueError("Expected '%s' property map, got '%s'" %
    178                          (names[t], names[prop.key_type()]))
--> 179     return pmap._get_any()
    180 
    181 

/Users/amaatouq/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/graph_tool/__init__.py in _get_any(self)
    389         g = self.get_graph()
    390         if t == "v":
--> 391             N = g.num_vertices(True)
    392         elif t == "e":
    393             N = g.edge_index_range

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'num_vertices'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in arf_layout(). You an work around it by making:

```
initial_pos = networks[0].own_property(initial_pos)
```

before using it further.